# Jquery Store Locator Plugin with https, SSL, secure URL: Does not work with custom domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl

**Jquery Store Locator Plugin**

Map plugin works when I use the web hosting server's secure url, but not when I use my own domain name's secure url.

```
Map does not load for:
https://mydomain.ext/mapstuff/default-location-example.html

Map does load via the server name url:
https://secureservername.com/~myusername/mapstuff/default-location-example.html
```

Is that just the way browsers handle cross-site jquery calls nowadays? The domain is seen as a mask and therefore untrustworthy, and applications such as Jquery Store Locator Plugin are automatically deactivated? Is there a solution for this issue for those of us who rent website hosting, aside from using the host's secure server name url?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND: PLUGIN NOW WORKS ON EITHER URL AND WITHOUT HTTPS ALSO.**

I had overlooked this line in the example html:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>

I needed to fill that out with an API key from Google Maps API:

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
```